# Show that AQ = x cos θ + y sin θ

Tags: trigonometry

Here is proberly a easy trigonometry question that i can't figure out

> In the diagram to the right, ABCD is a rectangle in which AB = x and BC = y. BP and CQ are drawn perpendicular to the interval AE, >which is inclined at an angle θ to AB.
>
> Show that
> $$AQ = x cos θ + y sin θ$$[image]
> Thanks

Comment: Try to show that $AP=x\cos\theta$ and that $PQ=y\sin\theta$ (the latter can be shown by adding a point $R$ on $PB$ such that $RPQC$ is a rectangle).

Comment: @RMWGNE96 Cool thanks, I think i got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Construct the perpendicular line  from Point $C$ to the line $$BP$$